# Extracting words from a string - delicate problem

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word

I need help in extracting words from a string in C++. In the definition of the exercise I'm trying to complete, a word is **any sequence of letters and numbers which is bordered by characters that are not letters or numbers(e.g. interpunction, whitespaces etc)**. For example:

```
This.Is.a.String
```

my program should create a vector of strings, where the elements of the vector would be individual words from the mentioned string, in this case "This", "Is", "a", "String".

I tried iterating through the given string with a for loop and to check a condition that whenever the character we're at right now IS (by ASCII value) anything between A and Z (a and z) and  the digits 0 and 9, put it into a string. Next, put that string in the vector and resize the string to 0 (so we can put another word.) That doesn't seem to work...

```
vector<string> Function(string s) {
    char letter;
    string r;
    vector<string> vector_string;
     for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        letter=toupper(s.at(i));  // I do this so all letters are capital letters, so it's easier to compare them
        r.resize(0);
   while((letter>=65 || letter<=90) && (letter>=48 || letter<=57)) {

        r.push_back(s.at(i));

    }
        vector_string.push_back(r);




}

 return vector_string;
  }
```

P.S. I am very new to C++. I know this is not anywhere near a solution but I had to start somewhere. I'd very much appreciate it if any of you could give help me on what to do here! It's kinda frustrating.

Thanks and sorry for taking your time!

Comment: Are you certain that you are including lowercase letters in that while loop? Also, how would that while loop terminate? You are making no modifications in the loop body to alter the variable in the loop's condition expression.

Comment: The `<regex>` header is your friend.

Comment: I think your `while` condition is the wrong way around - you want `while((letter>=65 && letter<=90) || (letter>=48 && letter<=57)) {`

Comment: @Steve That's only one of many errors.

Comment: Figuring out an algorithm to do this doesn't require any skill at C++. That's the first step. Translating that algorithm to C++ is the second step and that does require C++ skill. But I think you're stuck on the first step not the second, your C++ skills seem OK to me. So think about the algorithm without worrying about C++ too much.

Comment: Yes that's what I said. This does not make any sense at all and I kind of asked about what kind of approach to take to tackle this because I don't even know if my reasoning is good

Comment: @l0ner9 Well my approach would be to loop through the string in a single loop, but simultaneously hold a variable which is the start of the current word (if any). When you reach the end of a word, you can then extract the sub-string between the start of the current word and the current position.

Answer (score 0):

You have an endless while loop. And its condition is not correct.

Here an improvement:

```
vector<string> split(string s) {
    char letter;
    vector<string> vector_string;

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ) {
        if (isalnum(s[i])) {
            string r; 
            do {  
               r.push_back(s[i++]);
            } while(i<s.length() && isalnum(s[i]));
            vector_string.push_back(r);
        }
        else i++; 
    }
    return vector_string;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/txo9eu)

This revised version uses the predetermined [`isalnum()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) to take alphanumeric chars in the words.

For writing clearer conditions, as a general rule, prefer the use of the standard's character-classification predicates in [`<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype)  or better, their [locale-aware counterparts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale).

#### Edit: And if you could use regex ?

Not sure you're allowed, but here is how the code would look like:

```
vector<string> split(string s) {
    regex word_definition("([a-zA-Z0-9]+)");
    auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), word_definition);
    auto words_end = sregex_iterator();

    vector<string> vector_string;
    for(auto i = words_begin; i!=words_end; i++) {
        vector_string.push_back(i->str());
    }
    return vector_string;
}
```

Comment: Please add a emptiness check for r before pushing back to vector_string.

Comment: @ElvirCrncevic There was more than emptyness check  if testing with some random strings with more than one separator;-)

Comment: Might I also suggest adding isalpha for further code simplification?

Comment: @ElvirCrncevic yes, you may :-) Done !